# How to use CROSS APPLY in this scenario

Tags: sql-server

I have a ProductStatus table as listed below. I need to list all products whose latest status is “SU”. Along with that I need to list what was the previous status of this product.

Based on referring various posts, it seems like `CROSS APPLY` will be suitable for this. I made an attempt as listed below but that didn’t give the expected result.

What is the best way to achieve this in `SQL Server 2005` (without using subquery)?

```
DECLARE @ProductStatus TABLE (ProductStatusID INT,  productCode VARCHAR(5), statusCode VARCHAR(2))

INSERT INTO @ProductStatus

SELECT 1,'10011','RE'  --Recevied
UNION
SELECT 2,'10011','SU'  --Suspended

UNION
SELECT 3,'10012','IT'  -- In Transit
UNION
SELECT 4,'10012','RE' -- Received
UNION
SELECT 10,'10012','PR' -- Produced
UNION
SELECT 12,'10012','SU'  -- Suspended

UNION
SELECT 14,'10013','RE'  -- Recevied

UNION
SELECT 16,'10014','SU'  -- Recevied
UNION
SELECT 18,'10014','RE'  -- Recevied
```

CROSS APPLY attempt

```
SELECT *
FROM @ProductStatus P
CROSS APPLY 
(
   SELECT MAX(V.ProductStatusID) as maxVal
   FROM @ProductStatus V
   WHERE V.ProductCode = P.ProductCode
   AND V. ProductStatusID <  P.ProductStatusID 
   GROUP BY V.ProductCode   
)ML
WHERE P.statusCode = 'SU'
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

[image]

Comment: CROSS APPLY is generally required when using functions. I see no functions here. A CROSS JOIN is used when wanting to create a cross product (every combination of rows, in your case 9x9 = 81 rows). Again I see no reason for this. In short forget about CROSS anything.

Comment: @ElectricLlama Yes. ProductStatusID is the column used for finding previous

Comment: how about ... adding a row_number() windowed function to product id ordered by productstatusid desc, then select where row_number=1 and status = 'SU', joining to row_number=2 and product id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `cross apply` but I think `row_number()` is an easier approach:

```
select ProductCode,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then statusCode end) as LastStatus,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then statusCode end) as PrevStatus
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ProductCode order by ProductStatusId desc) as seqnum
      from @ProductStatus p
     ) p
group by ProductCode
having max(case when seqnum = 1 then statusCode end) = 'SU';
```

Answer (score 1):

Lijo, I've structured it as a CTE so you can see how I've developed my ideas.  You can refactor it as sub-queries without affecting the meaning if you are more comfortable with those.

```
;with MostRecentStatus as (
select
    MAX(ProductStatusID) as ProductStatusID,
    productCode
from @ProductStatus as p1
group by productCode
)
,MostRecentIsSU as (
select
    p2.ProductStatusID,
    p2.productCode,
    p2.statusCode
from MostRecentStatus as mrs
inner join @ProductStatus as p2
    on p2.ProductStatusID = mrs.ProductStatusID
    and p2.statusCode = 'SU'
)
select
    m.ProductStatusID,
    m.productCode,
    m.statusCode,
    p3.statusCode as PrevStatus,
    p3.ProductStatusID as PrevProductStatusID
from MostRecentIsSU as m
left outer join @ProductStatus as p3
    on p3.productCode = m.productcode
    and p3.ProductStatusID = m.ProductStatusID - 1;
```

**Edit**: ..and here's the ROW_NUMBER() version with kudos to @attila.

```
;with InSquence as
(
    select
        ProductStatusID,
        productCode,
        statusCode,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY productCode ORDER BY ProductStatusID desc) as Sequence
    from @ProductStatus
)
,FirstIsSU as
(
    select
        ProductStatusID,
        productCode
    from InSquence
    where Sequence = 1
    and statusCode = 'SU'
)
,PreviousCode as
(
    select
        ProductStatusID,
        productCode,
        statusCode
    from InSquence
    where Sequence = 2
)
select
    f.ProductStatusID,
    f.productCode,
    'SU' as CurrentStatus,
    p.statusCode as PrevStatus,
    p.ProductStatusID as PrevProductStatusID
from FirstIsSU as f
left outer join PreviousCode as p
    on p.productCode = f.ProductCode;
```

Comment: We cannot rely on `and p3.ProductStatusID = m.ProductStatusID - 1;` There can be other products data in between.. I have updated question with this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Here is a convoluted solution which serves mainly to illustrate that this should probably be done using `row_number()` :)

```
SELECT 
F.productCode, F.statusCode, F.productStatusID, F.PriorProductStatusID, PriorStatus.statusCode
FROM
(
SELECT 
PCS.productCode, PCS.statusCode, PCS.productStatusID, MAX(PS.productStatusID) PriorProductStatusID
FROM 
(
SELECT productCode, MAX(productStatusID) productStatusID
FROM @ProductStatus
GROUP BY productCode
) LatestStatus
INNER JOIN
@ProductStatus PCS
ON PCS.productCode = LatestStatus.productCode
AND PCS.productStatusID = LatestStatus.productStatusID
AND PCS.statusCode = 'SU'
LEFT OUTER JOIN
@ProductStatus PS
ON PS.productCode = PCS.productCode
AND PS.productStatusID < PCS.productStatusID
GROUP BY PCS.productCode, PCS.statusCode, PCS.productStatusID
) F
LEFT OUTER JOIN
@ProductStatus PriorStatus
ON  F.productCode = PriorStatus.productCode
AND F.PriorProductStatusID = PriorStatus.ProductStatusID
```

Comment: Actually I see that 10014 shouldn't be in the result because it's latest is not SU, it's RE. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, '10014' should not be there in the result.

Comment: you know, looking at the data further, my solution is completely incorrect! If @Atilla doesn't pose an answer, I will using his suggestion.

Comment: I've since altered my answer so it does produce the correct results, albeit not using `row_number()`